# How to trace the execution of a regex matching?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre, trace

Is there a convenient way to get a *trace* of the regex engine's states during the evaluation of a `m//` or `s///` expression?

---

BTW, I'm aware of that there is a [Regexp::Debugger package](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Regexp-Debugger-0.002000/lib/Regexp/Debugger.pm) available through CPAN (and it *is* amazingly cool), but I don't see a way to get anything like a trace from it; I don't want to step through a potentially huge number of steps.

Comment: On a related note, a module of interest is [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAPE::Regex::Explain), a module that "explains" (breaks down and annotates with comments) regular expression patterns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Turn the regex engine into debug mode and it'll print what it's doing:

```
use re 'debug'; 

my $str = "abcdefg";
$str =~ m/[ef]+/;
```

Which gives an output of:

```
Compiling REx "[ef]+"
Final program:
   1: PLUS (13)
   2:   ANYOF[ef] (0)
  13: END (0)
stclass ANYOF[ef] plus minlen 1 
Matching REx "[ef]+" against "abcdefg"
Matching stclass ANYOF[ef] against "abcdefg" (7 bytes)
   4 <abcd> <efg>            |  1:PLUS(13)
                                  ANYOF[ef] can match 2 times out of 2147483647...
   6 <abcdef> <g>            | 13:  END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "[ef]+"
```

Comment: If you don't feel like editing the script, you can enable it using `PERL5OPT=-Mre=debug script.pl`